# nodejs socket emit return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am trying to send to clients whenever a new connection issued.

My server side javascripts is :

```
var clients = 0;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
clients ++;
console.log(clients);
socket.broadcast.emit('connect',socket.clients);
}
```

and my client side js to handle:

> ```
> socket.on('connect', function (data) {
> console.log('on'+data);});
> ```
>
> the output is undefined (on undefined)

Where 's things wrong?

Comment: 'connect' is a predefined event in socket.io, you may want to change that.

Answer (score 3):

```
socket.broadcast.emit('connect',socket.clients);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this should be 'clients'
```

Also, `connect` is a pre-defined event with `socket.io`, so you shouldn't reuse it or it might give unexpected results.

FWIW: `socket.broadcast.emit` will send a message to all connections *except* the current one. If that's not what you want (you want the message to be sent to all connections), use `io.sockets.emit` instead).

Comment: still same undefined. Actually I put socket.broadcast.emit('connect',clients); on the first try then add socket.clients

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh yes, I updated my answer, there's another issue too.